# Inserting request body into database

Tags: go, sqlx

I'm developing an API using Go, SQLX, postgres and go-swagger.

In POST method handler I get a request body of a type defined and validated by swagger.
After validation I'd like to insert that into a postgres table.

I haven't found much documentation about the subject except for the following snippet:

```
sqlStatement := `
INSERT INTO users (age, email, first_name, last_name)
VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
RETURNING id`
  id := 0
  err = db.QueryRow(sqlStatement, 30, "jon@calhoun.io", "Jonathan", "Calhoun").Scan(&id)
```

Which means I need to describe every single field of the struct I want to persist.

Is there a method that will just take a struct to be saved in a table?

```
db.save(struct)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [in the examples in the README](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx#usage):

```
// Named queries can use structs, so if you have an existing struct (i.e. person := &Person{}) that you have populated, you can pass it in as &person
tx.NamedExec("INSERT INTO person (first_name, last_name, email) VALUES (:first_name, :last_name, :email)", &Person{"Jane", "Citizen", "jane.citzen@example.com"})
```

Comment: Actually I couldn't make it work... I still need to describe all the fields and all the values...

Comment: You still need to write the SQL, because `sqlx` doesn't write SQL (not a full ORM, it just maps struct fields to parameters/columns). But you don't have to specify a value for each column, you can just pass your struct.